# Jquery .submit not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a scrollable Jquery form that I am having trouble with. Everything is working except the actual form submission.

Here is the code for the section of the scripts im having problems with, no matter what I try and do the submit on click refuses to work!

HTML FOR FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="default-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="register" />
<input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />
```

JQUERY FOR FORM SUBMIT:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    $('#default-form').submit();
});
```

You can see all the code on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jSKMh/1/

And a live version here: https://www.geniusmoney.co.uk/users/register2.php (Just click through the script, form validation currently disabled)

Comment: cant work since you have defined this earlier: $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });

Comment: @Alex has the answer : `$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });` systematically forbids your form from being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Alex, sorry should of said this is a modified script, I found online

Comment: Removing that breaks the script

Comment: dont remove it, look at my answer

Comment: chinmay please go away from the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning submits with this line:

```
$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
```

your submit will never go out. Rather try this:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    $('#default-form').unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

Comment: awesome. do you understand what happened? :)

Comment: Simply doing `$("#default-frm")[0].submit()` would have worked too.

Comment: .get(0).submit() also :)

Comment: Thanks Alex yes I do understand what was happening and how return false was stopping the submit and I needed to undo that somehow for the last step to get it to submit :)

Answer (score 3):

Modify like this

```
<input class="send submit" type="button" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //send information to server
   $('#default-form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When you click at your submit button the page is submitted becuase of your submit button  . so you couldn't notice that . change it in button type. 
 so use like this 
<input class="send submit" type="button" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you are more-or-less trying to override the submit function of the submit button. Since you have it currently set as a submit button, it will submit your form onclick without any jQuery. You need to either change your type from submit to just a button or remove your jQuery.